# Does IDisposable always have to be disposed?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that contains a protected `IDbConnection` property. Within this class I have a function that will return an open `IDbConnection`. As a result, I thought the class should also implement the `IDisposable` class to ensure the `IDbConnection` gets disposed of properly.

This is what my class looks like -

```
public class MyConnection : IDisposable
{
    protected IDbConnection _connection;
    protected string _connectionString;

    public IDbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
        return _connection;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The way I use it is -

```
MyConnection mc = new MyConnection();

using(var cnn = mc.OpenConnection())
{
    // do stuff with cnn
}
```

That should handle the disposal of the connection when it is finished. Couple of questions on this -

1. Is the `IDisposable` inheritance necessary for `MyConnection`? My thinking is that it is just best practice since you could potentially have an open connection out of the class control.
2. If the `IDisposable` is required, should I instead be using it like this -

Disposing of both

```
using(var mc = new MyConnection())
{
    using(var cnn = mc.OpenConnection())
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see a reason MyConnection implements IDisposable, no need in that. Also it should be named MyConnectionFactory by looking at what it does

Comment: @YegorAndrosov that's what I'm asking. The only reason I did it because lets say someone opens a connection but doesn't dispose of it properly. Also, the naming is just shorthand, in reality I have a factory that creates these connections, and this is just a base class

Comment: Maybe this class should be static, no need for an instance. Then you can have helper routines to return what you need without worrying what the callers are going to do with it, you should encapsulate this.

Comment: @Trevor: Looks to me like there's more there that was removed in minimization.

Comment: Multiple calls to `OpenConnection` will prevent all but the last from being disposed. But you don't want to do that anyway, there's no way to know whether the connection is actually finished with when `MyConnection` is no longer needed.

Comment: Yes, there was more that was removed. I wish this could be static, but the real purpose of this class was to make a base class that has DI dependencies. Ultimately, I made a extension methods that use that open connection. I was trying to keep it private/protected, but then need to instantiate large classes for different connections.

Comment: Mistake #1: caching a SQL connection to save on opening them. It's inadvisable, and internal connection pooling manages connections much better. All you need to do is dispose the connection to make sure it returns to the pool. You *must* dispose your connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, what you have there should rather be named `MyConnectionFactory`, because that's what it does.

Since you're returning the connection, that is what needs to be disposed, not the factory itself. So your use case

```cs
MyConnectionFactory mc = new MyConnectionFactory();

using(var cnn = mc.OpenConnection())
{
    // do stuff with cnn
}
```

is the right approach. Disposing `mc` doesn't do anything useful here, because it disposes a member that *is* actually already disposed. You should even remove the member `_connection` from the class, because it doesn't really help you to keep it, as the caller cleans it up. That is, unless you want to keep the connection open, but then the callers *must not* dispose it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My initial intention when writing this library was to keep `OpenConnection` private/protected, but I wanted to put the bulk functionality into extension methods to make it a bit more lightweight. In order to do that I needed to make these members public which ultimately led to this question

Comment: Really, I am trying to protect against a user calling `OpenConnection` and not disposing it, but I guess the GC would handle that

Comment: Yes, it would. Could cause a bit of extra memory used temporarily, but shouldn't be to bad. IIRC the connections are internally cached anyway.